# Сохранить БД ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, база-данных, ado.net, sql

У меня есть подключение к базе данных.

```
public SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection(s_connection);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }
```

Затем делаю запрос на вставку данных такого вида:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = CreateConnection().CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Departments(Name, Phone) VALUES (@Name, @Phone);";
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
myCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = d.Name;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
myCommand.Parameters["@Phone"].Value = d.Phone;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Затем аналогичным способом пытаюсь вытащить данные из БД, но не учитываются только что вставленные. После перезагрузки программы все изменения видны. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlCommand myCommand = CreateConnection().CreateCommand();
```

не делайте так. у Вас в коде нигде не остаётся ссылки на открытое соединение с БД, а его нужно закрывать

а по-существу - используйте транзакции:

```
using(var connection = CreateConnection())
{
    SqlCommand myCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    myCommand.Connection = connection;
    myCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Departments(Name, Phone) VALUES (@Name, @Phone);";
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
    myCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = d.Name;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
    myCommand.Parameters["@Phone"].Value = d.Phone;
    try 
    {
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ошибка вставки/коммита
    }
    // данные добавлены и доступны для выборки
}
```

Comment: только этот вариант все равно не помог. изменения записываются в оперативную память и лишь только после перезагрузки программы в саму БД

Comment: ну, тогда покажите код выборки. после коммита новые данные должны быть доступны

и ConnectionString покажите сразу